# Water Filter System

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, water-filtration, old-pipes

We have a home built in 1920 with galvanized pipes. Is it okay to install a water filtration system using the galvanized pipes?

Comment: If the pipes are from 1920 also(have not been replaced), then they are at or very near end of life(80 to 100 years).  They are also probably almost clog up with stuff that might block the water filter up fast.  The answer is you can connect, but might want to check the pipes first.

Comment: Agree that you’re due for a re-pipe. Do it now in a planned/ organized fashion, rather than under duress in a short while.

Comment: And your filter installer is going to have a hard time when pipes crumble in their hands.

Comment: Might find after a re-pipe you don't need a filter, but it would depend on the water supply and type of filter.

Comment: Is it the _original_ galvanized plumbing installed in the (last) 20's, or has it been replaced since? A couple of pictures of the plumbing (overview photo and a couple of close ups), may help people assess the situation.